# MySQL SUM query remove multiply data

Tags: mysql

I need a MySql query to do the following: Select totalFWA but only once per fwa_id and SUM selected values.
Currently i tried with the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(totalFWA) 
  FROM fwo_sub_total 
  JOIN fwo_request fr 
  JOIN fwo_history fh 
    ON fr.id=fh.fwo_request_id 
 WHERE stage = 1 
   AND fr.stage = fh.changed_to_stage 
   AND (creation_date BETWEEN '2016-08-02' AND '2016-08-11') 
 GROUP BY fwa_id;
```

but doesn't work . if i remove SUM() it returns correct values for
totalFWA

```
93.15
140.3
115
599.35
95
45
45
```

And when i add SUM() it returns me this :

```
279.45000000000005
420.90000000000003
345
1798.0500000000002
285
135
135
```

for example i have 3 records with the same fwa_id and totalFWA value 45 (3*45)=135 . 
i need to sum all the correct values and return it on one row.

Comment: `join fwo_request as fr join` you forgot the `on` here

Comment: It's in the WHERE-part, although I would also prefer to keep it as an ON-clause

Comment: Thank you . I added ON-clause but it still returning me 3 rows of values that need to be SUM and returned on 1 column.